# How can I open emacs in a new window from a Cygwin terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, emacs, cygwin

On Linux it's as simple as typing:

```
emacs filename.txt &
```

What do I have to do to make the above work in Cygwin on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

If it's installed, `emacs-w32.exe`.  Use `C-x 5 2` to open a new frame.  This is very handy for `M-x ediff-buffers`, for example.

Comment: I should have said *when* it's installed.

Comment: Also, there is some weirdness with symlinks in `/etc/alternatives`.  I haven't found any documentation to rationalize it, but it's worth knowing it's there.